# iFilter doesn't crawl content

Tags: 2010, search, sharepoint-server

I have installed the iFilter from Adobe. 
After that I set the Regkeys like the following images:

Under "`..ContentIndexCommon/Filters/Extension/.pdf`"

[image]

under "`..Filters/.pdf`"

[image]

I also added a FileExtension Entry in the Search Configuration. 
The result is that I get the file result but it seems that the content wasn't crawled.

What can be wrong?

EDIT: I got the following Error during the (Full / incremental) crawl:

[image]

Comment: Did you run a full crawl?  Check your search logs and see if there are any error concerning the PDF documents.   Also are the PDF's image based - if so it wont be able to read the contents of the file, just metatdata properties stored with it.

Comment: I did a full and a incremental crawl. I added the information from the crawl log. The Pdf is a non image specific document

Comment: Just to make sure: Did you restart SharePoint Search Service?

Comment: Hi, yes I checked now two times all settings restarted the service. Also I did a index reset with a following full crawl. I don't get any results :-/